# Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page in which page class is inherited with `BasePage` class like this

```
public partial class Content_Document_DocumentGuideline : BasePage
```

so I am able to access `BasePage` class information like below

```
int accessPermission = this.AccessPermission;
```

Now I have a usercontrol in this page.

I wanted to access this base page information in that user control also.
So if I try to inherit this `BasePage` class in my usercontrol like this

```
public partial class Content_Document_GuideLinesList : BasePage
```

I am getting following error:

> Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

So if I want to user `BasePage` class information from usercontrol, what would be the approach?

Comment: your user control already have a reference to page, make the information public on basepage and then you can have access  on it

Comment: C# does not support multiple inheritence.  You will need the UserControl-derived class to have a BasePage-derived member.

Comment: thanks InvernoMuto.. So..... i Need to reassign this information to public variables in parent base then use them in usercontrol ??

Comment: yip, but as @ben-robinson say, probably you have to check if base of page IS BasePage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the members of BasePage from within the user control so long as you only ever use it on pages that inherit from BasePage. You may want to add a property to your user control for this.

```
public BasePage BasePage
{
    get
    {
        return Page as BasePage;
    }
}
```

Be aware this property will return null if you use the control on a page that does not inherit from `BasePage`. You may need to make some members of BasePage public if they are not already.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is an link between a class that `is` another class. In your example, A Control `is not`  a BasePage. It is contained in a Page. Think of a Page as the main outside Control container. [This page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80045/Composition-VS-Inheritance) could be a good start to learn. It deals with the difference between inheritance an composition.

About your specific question, there is, in `Control` class, a property that lets you access the `Page` that is currently containing it: look at [the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page(v=vs.100).aspx).